# Why does Bootsrap overwrite my local stylesheet?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Whenever I import bootstrap like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

it somehow overwrites my own css file even though i did not use any bootstrap things.

My .css looks like this

```
html {
    background-image: url(back.jpg);
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    
    }


    .box
    {
       
        margin: 80px; /* abstand außerhalb*/
        padding: 30px; /* abstand innerhalb*/
        width: auto;    /* länge breite*/
        height: auto;
        border-radius: 20px; 
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
       
        color: white; /*Schriftfarbe*/
    }

;
```

Here without Bootstrap
[image: without bootstrap]

And here with Bootstrap Stylesheet

[image]

My main index.php looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
    <title>Dashborad</title>

    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 


    <script type="text/javascript" src="/placeholder"></script>
 
</head>

<body>
    <div class = "box">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Without sharing your markup, it's not possible to tell, but chances are you're using classes that Bootstrap uses. You should probably want to load your CSS after Bootstrap CSS, and also probably not use generic names that are also targeted by Bootstrap. Also check your page's markup to see if you're using any additional classes already used by Bootstrap.

Comment: Please see [ask] and revise your post with enough information for us to help. Also, your custom stylesheet should be loaded _after_ Bootstrap.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to add my main file to the question, just edited it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Bootstrap stylesheet sets styles for the `body` and many other elements (read https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/content/reboot/), that your stylesheet does not touch. Also, if you don't want your styles overridden by Bootstrap, the proper way is to **always** include your stylesheet(s) **after** Bootstrap.

You can get rid of the body background by setting the value of the appropriate CSS variable:

```css
body{
  --bs-body-bg: transparent;
}
```

Here is a working example:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<style>
  html {
    background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/1600);
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
  }
  
  body {
    --bs-body-bg: transparent;
  }
  
  .box {
    margin: 80px;
    /* abstand außerhalb*/
    padding: 30px;
    /* abstand innerhalb*/
    width: auto;
    /* länge breite*/
    height: auto;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    color: white;
    /*Schriftfarbe*/
  }
</style>

<div class="box">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata.
</div>
```